# Shortcut for Windows Spotlight-like launcher

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, launcher, windows-spotlight

As described in [Microsoft’s new Spotlight-like launcher for Windows 10 will arrive in May](https://www.theverge.com/2020/4/17/21224904/microsoft-windows-10-launcher-powertoy-spotlight-alfred-details) there is now a Spotlight-like launcher. When cleaning my keyboard I accidentally opened it. Now I am wondering how I did this. Does anyone know what the shortcut is for this new launcher?

Comment: *Hint:* Windows Power Tools are required in order for it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Key code is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.  The first time, it only works if the focus is on the desktop.   Once you have invoked it and closed it.  It will pop anywhere you press the key sequence.

If you are used to using this for the Window/Application Menu, then you may want to change this shortcut.